# Check Whether A field of a table has been filled by BLOB

Tags: php, mysql, blob

I set up a table(blob_table) with 2 column: blob_name, blob_file.

The column blob_file was set NULL as default, and to be stored with BLOB.

After populate some rows with blob and some not, I try to run PHP below:

```
<?php

$con = new mysqli('localhost','root','root','database');
if ($con->connect_error) {die("error!");}

echo "<div><table><tr><th>Blob Not Yet Upload</th></tr>";

$sql = $con->prepare("SELECT blob_name FROM blob_table WHERE blob_file IS NULL");
$sql->execute();
$result = $sql->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<tr><td>".$row['blob_name']."</td></tr>";
} 
echo "</table></div>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

It didn't return anything, why? I am expecting that those blob_name for those NULL in blob_file column returned...

Comment: if you're trying to fetch something from a db, then why are you querying for a NULL value?

Comment: btw, you can get rid of `prepare/execute` and just use `query()`.

Comment: and that isn't the way to fetch/echo a blob image from db.

Comment: I am not fetching BLOB, but the blob_name of the BLOB.

Comment: see the answer given then, I obviously didn't grasp the question

Comment: `IS NULL` as an FYI, is not considered as "empty"; two different animals here. This I had a feeling from the beginning but your db schema is unknown. I either should have asked and/or you posting it from the beginning. That way, I'd of answered that from the get go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
   <?php

    $con = new mysqli('localhost','root','root','database');
    if ($con->connect_error) {die("error!");}

    echo "<div><table><tr><th>Blob Not Yet Upload</th></tr>";

    $sql = $con->query("SELECT blob_name FROM blob_table WHERE blob_file = '' ");

    while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$row['blob_name']."</td></tr>";
    } 
    echo "</table></div>";
    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: So whaddaya' gonna' do to fix it?

Comment: I fixed this @JayBlanchard